# user is able to edit other entity that is not for the same user, how can I prevent from this action?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, forms-authentication

I'm using `FormsAuthentication` for my application, when a user is authenticated, user can edit and change the `ID` parameter in url and user is able to change and edit other users' data, for solve this problem I use this solution:

```
[Authorize]
public ActionResult UserInfo(long id)
{
    var userViewModel = _userService.GetUserById(id);
   ** if (userViewModel.Username != HttpContext.User.Identity.Name)
        throw new UnauthorizedAccessException("we are not allowed to show other users' information to you");**
    return View(userViewModel);
}
```

But this is not a good solution because with this, I must check same logic for all of the actions to check that user is editing his/her own data
How can I solve it with an AOP solution in dbContext and `SaveChanges()` in it?

My User Class:

```
public string Username { get; private set; }
public string Password { get; private set; }
public string Name { get; private set; }
public DateTime? BirthDate { get; private set; }
public List<WishList.WishList> WishLists { get; private set; }
```

Other Classes:

```
public string Title { get; private set; }
public string Description { get; private set; }
public List<WishListItem.WishListItem> WishListItems { get; private set; }
public User.User User { get; private set; }
public long UserId { get; private set; }

public string Title { get; private set; }
public decimal RoughPrice { get; private set; }
public int Priority { get; private set; }
public WishList.WishList WishList { get; private set; }
public long WishListId { get; private set; }
```

My DbContext:

```
public class WishListManagementDbContext : System.Data.Entity.DbContext
{
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<BaseEntity> BaseEntities { get; set; }
    public DbSet<WishListItem> WishListItems { get; set; }
    public DbSet<WishList> WishLists { get; set; }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Configurations.AddFromAssembly(typeof(WishListManagementDbContext).Assembly);
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }

}
```

I'll appreciate if you can help me.

Comment: There seems to be no generic soulution to your problem. It strongly depends on what a user is allowed to do and why. 
Checking the UserId against something like a database seems to be required in some place.
This might be worth reading. 
https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/256985/how-to-control-authorized-access-to-specific-data-for-specific-users

Comment: every user has multiple WishList and every WishList has multiple items, I want that user would be able to edit own items, so user should not has access to other users' entities with changing params or WishListId in Url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible way to do it without having to write this code in every action is to use a global filter. It will execute automatically on every action call of your app.

Create a class that derives from `ActionFilterAttribute` and `IActionFilter`, and that overrides the method `OnActionExecuting`. So, for your case, it would be something like this:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters;

public class MyGlobalActionFilter : ActionFilterAttribute, IActionFilter
{
    //I am assuming you used DI for the service, so you can use it here too
    private readonly UserService _userService;
    public MyGlobalActionFilter(UserService userService)
    {
        _userService = userService;
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        var userViewModel = _userService.GetUserById(id);
        if (userViewModel.Username != HttpContext.User.Identity.Name)
            throw new UnauthorizedAccessException("we are not allowed to show other users' information to you");
    }
}
```

Then add it in your `Program.cs` file:

```
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews(options =>
{
    options.Filters.Add<MyGlobalActionFilter>();
});
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, this could help me but actually, I want to solve this problem with AOP solution and don't want to call a filter in every action, I want to override SaveChange() method of DbContext class so all of the actions will read that code automatically and I don't need to call my custom filter in every action by myself

Comment: When you add the filter in the Program.cs file as I mention in the last part of the answer, it will be called automatically on every action, no need to do anything else. It would be similar to overriding SaveChanges(), you will write code that will be executed automatically on every call

Comment: Oh now I got it, can I use it in.NET Framework too?

Comment: Yes, you can. Checkout this link https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/mvc/filters-in-asp.net-mvc